# Alternate form of cosine + sine into cosine

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to rewrite $\frac{2500}{13} \cos(1000t) - \frac{1200}{65} \sin(1000t)$ into a phrase that only is only a cosine. What trig identities are there to help me do this in general? I am not sure where to start to reformulate this.

Comment: $\cos(a+b)=\cos a\cos b-\sin a\sin b$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I don't think that applies to this

Comment: Look at [this](http://www.intmath.com/analytic-trigonometry/6-express-sin-sum-angles.php) which shows:$$a*\sin(\theta)\pm b*\cos(\theta)=R*\sin(\theta\pm\alpha)$$You can modify this to obtain the answer in terms of cosine.

Comment: sin(x) = cos(pi/2 - x)

Comment: My suggestion gives a way of rewriting as $C\cos(\alpha+1000t)$, where $\alpha$ and $C$ can be explicitly computed. If that's not the form you want, then disregard the above comment.

Comment: Suppose that you draw a right triangle with angle $\alpha$, adjacent side $2500/13$, and opposite side $1200/65$. Can you find the length of the hypotenuse, $R$? How about $\sin \alpha$ and $\cos \alpha$? Note that $R\sin\alpha = 2500/13$ and that $R\cos\alpha = 1200/65$.

Answer (score 1):

Try $$\sin^2\theta=1-cos^2\theta$$

You'll have to get creative, since this identity deals with squares.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the formula 
$$cos(x+y)=cos(x)cos(y)-sin(x)sin(y)$$

try to rewrite things .